# How to collapse multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, recursion, multidimensional-array

How to do that?

```
unpack_array([1, [10, 30, 40,[34,53],4],2]) -> [1,10,30,40,34,53,4,2]
```

I know that recursion must be applied. I tried, but it turns out to work only in one direction.

```
function unpack_array (arr, acc_arr=[]) {
  if (!arr) return acc_arr;
  let i = 0;
  while (arr[i] && !Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
    acc_arr.push(arr[i++])
  }
  return unpack_array(arr[i], acc_arr)
}
```

I believe that here need to use the "reduce" method.

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Take a look at `flat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method will work, so long as you supply it with an argument of `Infinity` to ensure that all levels of the multidimensional array are flattened:

```js
console.log([1, [10, 30, 40, [34, 53], 4], 2].flat(Infinity))
```

As an alternative, the linked documentation suggests a recursive `flatDeep` method, which uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to implement the desired behaviour:

```js
function flatDeep(arr) {
   return arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatDeep(val) : val), []);
};

console.log(flatDeep([1, [10, 30, 40, [34, 53], 4], 2]));
```

Comment: well there is `arr4.flat(Infinity);` ;)

Answer (score 2):

A simple recursive approach is to just call [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to combine each item into a single result but also recursively call `unpack_array` on the item. This way you handle nested arrays of any depth:

```js
function unpack_array(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return [arr];
  
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc.concat(unpack_array(item)), [])
}

console.log(unpack_array([1, [10, 30, 40,[34,53],4],2]))// -> [1,10,30,40,34,53,4,2]
```

The terminal condition for the recursion is if you reach an item that is not an array. You don't *have* to do `return [arr]` in that case, a simple `return arr` also works, but it's just more consistent this way - you can call `unpack_array(7)` and get an array back.

Comment: back in the old days, we did it like this: `while(a.some(Array.isArray)) a=[].concat.apply([], a)`